# How to use history with React, Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, browser-history

I am implementing a function that moves to My Page when a button is clicked.
However, when implemented in TS, the method used in JS gives an error.
I need help figuring out how to fix it.

```
//Topbar.tsx
function Topbar() {

  const history = useHistory()

  return (
    <header className="topbar">
        <button className="account_logo">
          <FaUserCircle className="logo" onClick = {() => {history.push('/mypage')}}/>
        </button>
      </div>
}
```

```
//App.tsx

import "./styles/app.scss";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {

  return (
    <div className = "app">
      <Topbar/>
      <section>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact = {true} path = "/" component = {Home}/>
          <Route path = "/mypage" component = {Mypage}/>
          <Route path = "/registerpage" component = {RegisterPage}/>
          {/* Not Found */}
          <Route component = {() => <Redirect to = "/" />} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I do the above, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
> at onClick

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

**You need to put your `TopBar` inside `BrowserRouter` to use `useHistory` hook:**

```
import "./styles/app.scss";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {

  return (
    <div className = "app">
      <section>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Topbar/> // <--- Your TopBar should be here
        <Switch>
          <Route exact = {true} path = "/" component = {Home}/>
          <Route path = "/mypage" component = {Mypage}/>
          <Route path = "/registerpage" component = {RegisterPage}/>
          {/* Not Found */}
          <Route component = {() => <Redirect to = "/" />} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```